# I flashed recoveries with Odin, why doesn't my phone boot bow?

Tags: adb, samsung, fastboot, bootloader, odin

Samsung S3 Android phone, not rooted, stock firmware.

In chronological order:
I turned on USB debugging, although could not use fastboot.
I used Odin to flash multiple recoveries, but I don't think I was successful, I believe the phone must have been rooted first. I downloaded some recoveries as .tar.md5 but I also downloaded .img and I tried to turn it into a .gz
- at that stage my phone still did boot Android, but normal recovery stopped working (Volume Up + Home + Power)
- Then I went to settings and chose Factory reset. Now all I've got is Odin mode.
It reads: 
Custom binary: Custom
System Status: Custom

Did I soft brick my phone ?

I din't loose data but I'd like to know in what state my phone is. 
Although I didnt intend to have an Android phone, now that I have one I will also try to mess up and change the bootloader if possible.
Thank you for taking the time and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the phone can still boot into Odin mode the best thing to do here is to flash a stock firmware and start all over again. You could have flashed a wrong recovery hence the boot failure; it happens. Just get and flash a full stock firmware in Odin. Make sure the firmware is for your device model and network/region. Samsung phones  have a tendency to require you flash the exact same firmware for your region/ network.

Comment: Indeed I did flash a stock rom, and I was surprised to find out that it was considered an update, so my data is still there.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the case. Since you've flashed a wrong recovery, the recovery changes the kernel of the phone which makes it non bootable. flash your stock rom and everything will be alright.

You can't convert a ".img" file to ".gz" and flash it. If you want to flash a custom recovery edit the ".tar.md5" file by opening it with any zip extractor such as WinRAR and put the recovery you want to flash.
You won't be able to boot into the phone system but you should be able to boot into the recovery mode.